# Grouping lines in a text file using python

Tags: python, text

I have a huge set of data that im trying to analyze (the data is in a text file)

heres an example:

```
0000:name=max
     age=19
     grade= 90
     hair color= brown
     eyes color= blue
     end

0001:name=jack
     age=18
     grade= 91
     hair color= black
     eyes color= blue
     end
0002:name=kay
     age=21
     grade= 70
     hair color= red
     eyes color= blue
     end
```

I was trying to save the data in excel table with columns that contains names ,ages,etc. what i did is to search for specifec words like `'age'` or `'name'` and then save it, but sometimes in some cases its tricky. so i thought of grouping each student alone and then search within this group.

I realized that each group starts with 4 digits and colon and each group ends with `end`, so i think thats the best idea of grouping

Which library should i use?

any tips would be very helpful
Thanks

Comment: I don't think you need any library to parse this file. Just read it line by line and parse - 
id:
key=value
key2=value2
end
...

Please share your code after attempting to parse if you are stuck anywhere. I am happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to parse the file:

```py
def retrieve_data_as_dict(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as file:
        data = []
        entry = dict()
        for line in file.readlines():
            line = line.strip()
            
            if line == "end":
                data.append(entry)
                entry = dict()
            elif line != "":
                if len(line.split(":")) > 1:
                    line = line.split(":")
                    line.pop(0)
                    line = ":".join(line)
                key, value = line.split("=")
                entry[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    return data

print(retrieve_data_as_dict("data.txt"))
```

If the content of `data.txt` is as you defined above, this sample will output

```
[{'name': 'max', 'age': '19', 'grade': '90', 'hair color': 'brown', 'eyes color': 'blue'}, {'name': 'jack', 'age': '18', 'grade': '91', 'hair color': 'black', 'eyes color': 'blue'}, {'name': 'kay', 'age': '21', 'grade': '70', 'hair color': 'red', 'eyes color': 'blue'}]
```

With these datas in a dictionary, you can now easily manipulate them in your program as you wish and add them to a csv file that excel can handle using Python's [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: im getting this error :ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Could you send the full file content you are trying to parse? For the extract you posted, it works just fine for me, so there may be irregularities in your file somewhere.

Comment: The names and the 4 digits are in the same line, is that a problem?

Comment: how can i fix that? because i cant change the text file format

Comment: I edited the answer to match this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Is this want you want?

```
import pandas as pd

with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines = [
        line.strip().rsplit("=")[-1].strip() for line
        in f.readlines() if line.strip() != "end"
    ]

    pd.DataFrame(
        [lines[i:i + 5] for i in range(0, len(lines), 5)]
    ).to_csv(
        "data.csv",
        index=False,
        header=["Name", "Age", "Grade", "Hair Color", "Eye Color"],
    )
```

Output a `.csv` file that looks like this:

[image]